# Showing that a set is in terminal $\sigma$-Algebra

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am reading a probability theory book (from Bauer) and I found the following statement in the book that I cant understand:

Given a sequence of independent random variables $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ and a zero sequence $(\tau_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and fix some $m\in\mathbb{N}$. The author claims that the set

$$A = \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \bigcup_{N=m}^\infty  \left\{  \sup_{n\geq N} \left| \tau_n \sum_{i=m}^n X_i \right| \leq \frac{1}{k}  \right\} \ $$

lies in the terminal $\sigma$-Algebra, i.e.
$$A  \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \sigma (X_l ; l \geq n ). $$

Therefore, I guess I have to show that

$$ A  \in \sigma(X_l; l \geq n) $$
for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

But I do not see that this holds. In fact, I only see that

$$ A  \in \sigma(X_l; l\geq m) .$$
Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first notice that your set $A$ can be writen as
$$A=\{\omega \mid\lim_{n\to\infty}\tau_n\sum_{i=m}^nX_i(\omega)= 0\}.$$
Since $\tau_n\to 0$, the above limit does not depend on any fixed number of $X_i(\omega)$'s. Hence, for any fixed $m_0\geq m$, you also have
$$A=\{\omega \mid \lim_{n\to\infty}\tau_n\sum_{i=m_0}^nX_i(\omega)= 0\}.$$
Now, go back to your first definition of $A$, with $m_0$ instead of $m$ and you're done.