# Understanding terminal $\sigma-$algebra and related notation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, notation, random-variables

I need some clarification about this "statement" in my notes, which I find unclear and I could not find anything really comprehensive around. I am studying for an exam so it's important.

"Be $(X_n)$ a sequence of random variables. Be $(\mathcal{G}_n) := \mathcal{F}(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, and $\mathcal{G}_n$ is not increasing.
$$\mathcal{G} := \bigcap_n \mathcal{G}_n$$
is called terminal $\sigma-$ algebra of $(X_n)$."

My confusions about this are the following:

- I don't understand this notation: $\mathcal{F}(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. Is this a sort of "the sigma algebra generated by all those random variables"? Even if that were the case, I don't understand the meaning.
- Why we require $\mathcal{G}_n$ not increasing?
- I cannot find a good definition / explanation of what a terminal $\sigma-$ algebra means in "concrete". What is its purpose? Why we need it?

Thank you!!

Comment: There are mistakes in your notes. The question makes little sense, and there is no notion of terminal $\sigma-$ algebra. Perhaps you mean tail  $\sigma-$ algebra.

Comment: @geetha290krm What mistakes? Also I looked around and I found no equivalence between tail and terminal. I mean, apparently they are both used but I ignore if they are equivalent... Anyway those are my notes, if there are mistakes I would appreciate them to be corrected if possible

Comment: According to your notations $\mathcal G=\sigma (X_1)$.

Comment: I searched the net for terminal $\sigma-$ algebra and I only got this question. Tell me which book has such a notion.

Comment: @geetha290krm https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3682543/generating-the-terminal-sigma-algebra, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864057/showing-that-a-set-is-in-terminal-sigma-algebra, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3090753/intuition-behind-terminal-sigma-algebra and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4521080/generate-terminal-sigma-algebra-to-use-komologorov-0-1-law

Comment: Probably tail sigma algebra. What is confusing, however, is $G_n$ not increasing (or monotone), if those are sigma algebras generated by the first $n$ variables, then it's immediately monotone.

Comment: @geetha290krm Terminal sigma algebra is also used here, under "formulation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero–one_law

Comment: Yes, in English that's called a "tail sigma algebra".

Comment: @AlvinL Thank you! I will then search for it, even if I found little so far... So what about the "not increasing sequence" part? I'm still confused by those definitions though

Comment: The definitions in your links clearly tell what mistakes you have made. Just replace your definition by the one in your first link. Terminal $\sigma-$ algebra is probably a translation from some other language and standard Probability books use the term tail $\sigma-$ algebra.

Comment: @geetha290krm According to the first link and my notation, then $\mathcal{G}_n = \sigma(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ means that $\mathcal{G}_n$ is a sequence of sigma algebra generated by the sigma algebras of the first $n$ random variables? 

I don't really understand this in concrete. $\mathcal{G}_1 = \sigma(X_1)$, $\mathcal{G}_2 = \sigma(X_1, X_2)$ and so on... What is then the point of having the tail sigma algebra as the intersection, since as you pointed out before it would be just $\sigma (X_1)$?

Comment: There would be no point to take intersection of such objects and that's not how tail sigma algebras are obtained, either.

Comment: @AlvinL Then I am not getting anything of this. And what is written in "formulation" in wikipedia page I linked above is even more confusing

Comment: @Numb3rs I have attempted to explain what a tail event is, but I can't comment on everything you have written in your notes, because much of it is nonsense.

Comment: The downvotes are likely due to them being your notes and you asking other people to make sense of what you have written.

Comment: @AlvinL Ye, and I am sorry if my notes are nonsense, but those are notes wrote from my professor one year ago... Which by the way is retired

Answer (score 3):

Curiously, the wikipedia page for [Kolmogorov 0-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law) also refers to this object as the "terminal sigma algebra". The more commonly used term is the "tail sigma algebra".

It is obtained as follows. Denote
$$T_n := \sigma (X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots) = \sigma \left(\{X_k^{-1}(B) \mid B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R), k\geqslant n\} \right),\quad n\in\mathbb N.$$
The intersection $T := \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} T_n$ is called the tail sigma algebra.

Tail events, i.e elements of $T$, are those whose outcome does not depend on any finite selection of the given variables. In other words, the beginning of the sequence does not matter. Kolmogorov 0-1 states that if we have a sequence of independent variables, then any tail event has probability of either $0$ or $1$.

Naturally, $\emptyset,\Omega\in T$. Other examples of tail events include the following:

1. $\exists \lim X_n := \{\omega \mid \exists \lim X_n(\omega)\}$
2. $\limsup X_n<\infty := \{\omega \mid \limsup X_n(\omega) < \infty\}$

..and so on. Whatever you can think of that makes use of upper\lower limits qualifies.